# Why "container1" is not displaying?

Tags: html, css

I'm having problem with my div (container1), it does't show on the webpage view, I also done some editing on my cascading style sheet and browse in google, unfortunately still doesn't solve my problem.

**See below:**

**CSS**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
header, nav, section, article, aside, footer {
    display: block;
}
body {
    font: 12px/18px Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}
a {
    color: blue;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0 18px
}
img {
    border: none;
}
input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
}


/* Header
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#header {
    height: 150px;
    background: #FFE680;
}
*/

/* Middle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#content {

    padding: 0 0 200px;
    height: 550px
}

#container1 {
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    -moz-column-gap: 1px;
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1px;
    column-count: 1;
    column-gap: 1px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    left:400px;
    top: -100px;
}


/* Footer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#footer {
    margin: -100px auto 0;
    min-width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #BFF08E;
    position: relative;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
</head>

<body>  

    <div id="wrapper">

        <header id="header">
            <strong>Header:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tortor. Praesent dictum, libero ut tempus dictum, neque eros elementum mauris, quis mollis arcu velit ac diam. Etiam neque. Quisque nec turpis. Aliquam arcu nulla, dictum et, lacinia a, mollis in, ante. Sed eu felis in elit tempor venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut ultricies porttitor purus. Proin non tellus at ligula fringilla tristique. Fusce vehicula quam. Curabitur vel tortor vitae pede imperdiet ultrices. Sed tortor.
        </header><!-- #header-->

        <div id="content">
            <strong>Content:</strong> Sed placerat accumsan ligula. Aliquam felis magna, congue quis, tempus eu, aliquam vitae, ante. Cras neque justo, ultrices at, rhoncus a, facilisis eget, nisl. Quisque vitae pede. Nam et augue. Sed a elit. Ut vel massa. Suspendisse nibh pede, ultrices vitae, ultrices nec, mollis non, nibh. In sit amet pede quis leo vulputate hendrerit. Cras laoreet leo et justo auctor condimentum. Integer id enim. Suspendisse egestas, dui ac egestas mollis, libero orci hendrerit lacus, et malesuada lorem neque ac libero. Morbi tempor pulvinar pede. Donec vel elit.
        </div><!-- #content-->


        <div id="container1">
        Sed placerat accumsan ligula. Aliquam felis magna, congue quis, tempus eu, aliquam vitae, ante. Cras neque justo, ultrices at, rhoncus a, facilisis eget, nisl. Quisque vitae pede. Nam et augue. Sed a elit. Ut vel massa. Suspendisse nibh pede, ultrices vitae, ultrices nec, mollis non, nibh.
        </div>
    </div><!-- #wrapper -->

    <footer id="footer">
        <strong>Footer:</strong> Mus elit Morbi mus enim lacus at quis Nam eget morbi. Et semper urna urna non at cursus dolor vestibulum neque enim. Tellus interdum at laoreet laoreet lacinia lacinia sed Quisque justo quis. Hendrerit scelerisque lorem elit orci tempor tincidunt enim Phasellus dignissim tincidunt. Nunc vel et Sed nisl Vestibulum odio montes Aliquam volutpat pellentesque. Ut pede sagittis et quis nunc gravida porttitor ligula.
    </footer><!-- #footer -->

</body>
```

Comment: It seems like it shows... http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/JMVP5/

Comment: Yes it shows on the JSFiddle, but in my GC Browser it doesn't. I'll try it with another browser.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Thanks! it works, It's my fault anyways, I set up "top" position of my "container1" to **-100** that's why it doesn't show up. fail again, BTW thanks.